# After I ran certbot browsers cannot access css file

Tags: nginx, debian, certbot, css

After I ran `certbot --nginx` browsers cannot access css of my website.

`style.css` is located in `./styles` of root of my site.
The error is `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID style.css:1`

Edited: string from my `.html` files (where `example.com` is my site domain):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/styles/style.css">
```

Edited: my `tree -p` output:

```
.
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  about
│   ├── [-rw-r--r--]  index.html
│   └── [-rw-r--r--]  index.md
├── [-rw-r--r--]  icon.ico
├── [-rw-r--r--]  index.html
├── [-rw-r--r--]  index.md
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  styles
│   ├── [-rw-r--r--]  prev.css
│   └── [-rw-r--r--]  style.css
└── [drwxr-xr-x]  templates
    └── [-rw-r--r--]  temp.html
```

Edited: new error ocured:

```
example.com/:5 GET https://www.example.com/styles/style.css net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

What should I do to solve the issue?

Comment: Could you show the first line of `style.css`, please? I think there is a wrong `@import` or something.

Comment: Hi! No, I didn't use ```@import``` in my ```style.css```. It used to work until recently.

Comment: Please add the output of `nginx -T` to the question so we can see your full nginx configuration. Most likely Certbot has made bad changes to the configuration.

Comment: does the cert include www and domaun only, it is telling strictly that something is wrong on the line one, please show us eother the real domain name or the content of the file

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue putting `www.example.com` into my `server_name` except `example.com`. Thank you everyone for your answers.